# JsonHttpResponseHandler - get jsonObject?

Tags: android, json

I am using the [`JsonHttpResponseHandler`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html) library in my android app to receive a `JSONObject`. The problem is that I can only do work with `JSONObject` inside of `onSuccess` function. Does anybody know how to return the `JSONObject`? I think the function

```
protected java.lang.Object parseResponse(byte[] responseBody)
```

is promising but I do not know what to put in as the parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably link the lib you're using.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to post it, http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html

Comment: I dont understand?  Why can't you work with the JSONObject outside of onSuccess?  Just pass it through to whatever functions you need to operate on the object.

Comment: I have tried, can you please give me an example?